# Single Column Value from Row in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I have a data like this:

```
1, 0, 0
0, 1, 0
0, 0, 1
```

Need the output to be:

```
1, 1, 1
```

How can do this in Pig?

Comment: The input data is like below. Row 1 - 1,0,0 Row2 - 0,1,0 Row3 - 0,0,1

Comment: Google the words `apache pig SUM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input

```
1, 0, 0
0, 1, 0
0, 0, 1
```

Just Create a new variable in each row with same value  and apply grouping using that key and take MAX for each variable ..

```
records = LOAD '/user/cloudera/records.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (c1:int,c2:int,c3:int);

records_each = FOREACH records GENERATE 'KEY' as grouping_key, c1, c2, c3;

records_grp  = GROUP records_each BY grouping_key;

records_grp_each = FOREACH records_grp GENERATE MAX(records_each.c1) as c1, MAX(records_each.c2) as c2, MAX(records_each.c3) as c3;
```

output :

```
 (1,1,1)
```